# What is the difference between request.POST and dictionary data in django forms?

Tags: django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

No problem when I write the code like this without using ajax:

```
form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

but when using ajax I get an error when I write the code like this(post: 500 (Internal Server Error)):

```
data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
data = QueryDict(data)

form = {
    "product_name": data.get('name'),
    "description": data.get('description'),
    "price": data.get('price'),
    "quantity": data.get('quantity')
}
form = UploadForm(data=form)
```

I did not know what to do, but the form needed to get this dictionary data.Is there a difference between the request.post and the dictionary data, which is a problem? thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because encoding isn't specified and since you want to update the dict set the mutable to `True` which is not recommended.

```
# To get a mutable copy of the POST data using copy.

import copy

data = copy.copy(request.POST)


# Unsafe

data = QueryDict(request.body, encoding='utf-8', mutable=True)

data['b'] = '1'
```

To send post request with Ajax for django you need to setup the headers required.

Pre Ajax setup: `pre-ajax.js`

```
const Cookies = require('js-cookie');

(($) => {
  const csrfSafeMethod = method => /^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method);
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.method) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
      }
    },
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

In the html or javascript file this script should be used before the script tag.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'pre-ajax.js' %}"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'your-script-that-send-post.js' %}">`

Comment: hello jackotonye; When I try the request.post copy method, the return value is empty.i guess i could send the data with ajax.I had to use the request.body method.how can I clean data when using this method(for request.body).do you have an idea.thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: I also add control is false with form is_valid function.data = QueryDict(request.body, encoding='utf-8', mutable=True) this method causes the form to return incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sending the `'X-CSRFToken'` as a header in the Ajax request.

Comment: when I write the above code I get the following error: `code`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined for const Cookies = require('js-cookie');`code`

Comment: I am able to get the request.POST data when I am making the following correction in the ajax code ,contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8' , but when I check the form is_valid I still get the value of false.

Comment: What fields are used in the form and can you update the question with the code of the form class and the view logic.

Comment: hello jackotonye, Thank you very much for your help